# How to replace a value in a file with other value in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program in Python to search for `value1` in `column1` from a table which is in a file and if it exists, replace `value2` in the same row of the table. The table has values in rows and columns separated by space. The first three lines of file contain text so in my code I have skipped first three lines and searched from the first element of first column. I have written the code in python( beginner in python). I am using replace function to replace value2 with new value. There is no error but the replace method is not working. The value is not modified in the file. I searched for similar questions in stackoverflow and implemented it but couldn't land at the correct output. It would be of great help if you could help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Skip first three header lines...

```
0  2.00000E-01  2.00000E+00  1.00000E-01  1.00000E-01  0.00000E+00  1.00000E-01    5315.58609617651
5  8.61341E-02  9.32377E-01  1.03878E-01  9.66092E-02  0.00000E+00  1.31608E-01    4874.21137697405
10  9.01592E-02  1.01589E+00  1.02249E-01  1.16872E-01  0.00000E+00  1.37603E-01    4868.99427672864
14  9.16065E-02  1.02727E+00  1.02914E-01  1.15918E-01  0.00000E+00  1.34975E-01    4868.85701581641
-1000000000  9.16065E-02  1.02727E+00  1.02914E-01  1.15918E-01  0.00000E+00  1.34975E-01    4868.85701581641
-1000000001  4.76910E-03  5.52689E-02  9.21654E-03  2.79153E-02  1.00000E+10  2.92135E-02   0.000000000000000E+000
-1000000004  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  3.20802E-01  3.40467E-01  0.00000E+00  3.67390E-01   0.000000000000000E+000
-1000000005  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.43648E-02  4.09956E-02  1.00000E+10  3.97582E-02   0.000000000000000E+000
```

My code:
    #python
    import sys
    # To open a file foce.ext and read the contents

```
iteration=[]
obj_value=[]
with open('ex_foce.ext','r+') as file:
#to skip first three lines and store the elements in 1st and 8th column in two arrays
    line1=file.readlines()[2:]

    for line in line1:
        if line:
            information=line.split()
            iteration.append(information[0])
            obj_value.append(information[7])
    print(line1)

    print(iteration)

    print(obj_value)
    pos=iteration.index('-1000000000')
    print(pos)
    #replacing value2 by 1.0
    obj_value[pos]=1.0
    print(obj_value[pos])
    old_value=obj_value[pos]
    line_number=pos
    x=line1[line_number]
    file.write(x.replace( str(old_value), "1.0" ))

file.close()
```

Comment: if you provide some ipout and expected output I am sure there is an easy way to achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am trying to include contents of my file in the post but not able to retain formatting. This is my first post. It would be great if you could tell me how to add contents of my file without losing the formatting. can i attach the file?

Comment: just add it and I will format it for you

Comment: Thanks a lot Padraic. I have added the content of the file to the post. First line ends with "objective function", second line ends with  "Iteration2=0" , 3rd line with "OBJ", from 4th line onwards, every line has 8 numbers in a line. Hope this helps in formatting the content. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: no worries, I added answer that replaces the value with `1.0` wherever you have a '-1000000000' which I think is what you want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the fact that you want to use the `r+` opening mode for reading and writing. Even to change just one character in your file, here is the best way to proceed (I have written thousands of these):

```
f = open("ex_foce.ext","r")        # original file for reading
g = open("ex_foce_mod.ext","w")    # "output", modified file
for _ in range(3):
    g.write(f.readline())          # copy header lines
for line in f:
    L = line.strip().split()
    if L[0]=='-1000000000': L[7] = '1.0'
    g.write(' '.join(L)+'\n')
f.close()
g.close()
```

This will

1. avoid losing data from the original file if the program fails;
2. always produce the result you want without any problem;
3. never load the entire file in memory (as `readlines()` does);
4. not bother about the line index where you found the result (although you can get it using `enumerate` on `f` instead).

When finished sucessfully, you can remove the original manually (or with `os.remove`/`shutil.rmtree`). Forget about in-file editing, although it seems more intuitive at first. If you are afraid of leaving a lot of temporary files in the process, use appropriate tools such as [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I compiled the code. There is no error but in ex_foce_mod.ext file, the values are written starting from value 10 which is 3rd row of the table. The text which was in the beginning of the file is not written and the value '-1000000000' is not replaced by '1.0'. Could you help me?

Comment: Moreover it looks like your input file has two spaces as a separator... So use `split()` or `split('  ')` instead of `split(' ')`. Anyway at this point you can try and print some values to see if it splits correctly.

Comment: I compiled the code. It is throwing error for the line -             if L[0]=='-1000000000':L[7]='1.0' saying indexerror: Link index out of range. I tried others' code too and got the same error. Is it because -1000000000 is a big number??

Comment: You are right. There are two whitespaces between elements in the table. I changed it to split('  ') but there is no change in the file.

Comment: IndexError probably because you have a line without an element [7]. Try [-1] instead if it is the last element. This number is not big at all. Change to `split()`, and `print line`, `print L`.

Comment: Thanks a lottt for your help Muraveill..!!! I changed element[7] to [-1] and it worked fine. Though the formatting of the table of the table is lost for first few lines, the value is over written. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The format of the output depends entirely on the character you use for `join`. You may prefer `'\t'.join(L)` instead of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `line1=file.readlines()[2:]`, the "cursor" moves to the end of the file. Then you ask to write the line with the replaced value, so isn't it copied at the end of the file instead of being just modified in place? Maybe you miss a `file.seek(...)` call before writing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I am trying to understand the seek method. seek(x) will point to the Xth byte in the file is what I understood. PLease correct me if I am wrong. Now I need to go to the line where my search element(value1) matches in the first column and move to the last element of that row. Can I mention the line number in the seek()?

Comment: Using `seek` will leave garbage at the end of the file in case the new contents are smaller than the old one.

Comment: True. This was really to try and keep using the `r+` opening mode. But almost always you want to open one file for reading, and a second one for writing. This way you 1. avoid the problem 2. will not lose the original data.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of the question is correct, you want the following:

**Edit1, after clarification via comment**

**Edit2, to preserve preliminary information**

```
# ... define value1, value3 ...
with open('ex_foce.ext') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    prelims = '\n'.join(lines[ : 2])
    lines = lines[2: ]
toWrite = ''
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith(value1):
        toWrite += ' '.join(line.split()[ : -1]) + value3 + '\n'
    else:
        toWrite += line + '\n'
with open('ex_foce.ext', 'w') as f:
    f.write(prelims + '\n' + toWrite);
```

Replace `value1` and `value3` as required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I need to search for value1 in the column1 of the table and for example if I find value1 in the 3rd row of the column1, then I have to change some other value2 which is the last element in the same row by another number say value3. I hope my problem is clear.

Comment: I've edited my answer. This new version should hopefully be helpful.

Comment: I really appreciate the time and effort taken by you in helping me. I edited accordingly and ran the code. But it is erasing even the first three lines of the file which were there and the value is not replaced in the file. Could you suggest anything?

Comment: I've added some code to preserve preliminary information which was previously being lost. Also, fixed splitting by changing `split[ : -1]` to `split()[ : -1]`. Things should now work as expected. Keep me posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edited code. I am not getting error but the value "-1000000000" is not getting overwritten by '1.0'. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to do it is;

- Open the file for reading
- Read all the lines from the file.
- Close the file
- Manipulate the lines how you want
- Open the file for writing (this will truncate the file)
- Write the changed files back to the file
- Close the file

You could open the file for reading and writing, and then use `seek` to go back to the beginning. But that would leave garbage at the end of the file if the new contents are smaller than the old one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you elaborate on points 4 and 5? I have been trying various ways of modifying the table but none of them is giving me the right result. Could you plz help me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('ex_foce.ext','r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # don't slice, we need to use all lines later
    for ind, line in enumerate(lines[3:]): # keep track of the index of each line using enumerate from line 4 to the end
        spl = line.split()
        if (spl[0]) == '-1000000000': # if we find value
            lines[ind] = line.replace(spl[7],"1.0") # replace line in lines at ind/index with updated value
    f.seek(0) # go back to start of file
    for line in lines: # write updated lines
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited accordingly but getting an error as Indexerror: List index out of range, pointing to spl[0]. I have been trying to get rid of the error but not able to. Could you help me?

Comment: indexerror: List index out of range and the error is pointing to the line- if(spl[0])=='-1000000000':

Comment: print spl and line to see what it is

Comment: Yes I tried even that. print(spl[0]) is also giving the same error.

Comment: print line before that, it is more than likely an empty line